# Paypal canceling recurring profile buyer email notification

Tags: paypal

I am useing paypal exprees checkout API. I want to cancel recurring profile. I add a note for reason of canceling. The recurring profile cancel successfully and note setup to buyer profile history page. But The note does show buyer email notification.

Can you tell anyone how can I show user reason of cancellation in email notification?

Thanks advance

Answer (score 0):

That note is considered an internal use sort of thing, and isn't meant to be shown to the buyer.

What you can do, though, is setup an [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) solution which would get hit when the profile is canceled.  Within this you can generate a custom, branded email notification, update your database, hit 3rd party web services, etc.  It's a very useful tool that allows you to automate all sorts of things based on different transaction types.